# Running Shelve android open source project

Tags: android

Hi I am a beginner in android, I've checked out Shelve android project form http://code.google.com/p/shelves/. Then I created a new Intelij Idea for android project, so I copied all files in the project except Idea files. But when I want to run the project, there are some errors in AddBookActivity class related to this line:

import org.curiouscreature.android.shelves.R;

it can not resolve symbol R.

There isn't any R class in the above path. What should I do ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: R is the generated java class, so if R is missing then something is keeping the project from building. Check the project setup.

Comment: thanks for reply, do you mean I should config the Idea project for generating R class from specified path? Do you know how ?

Comment: No I don't as I use eclipse. But if you know that  your project isn't being built then you should have enough of a springboard to dive into Google.